# Why Lie Groupoid inversion is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm actually discovering Lie groupoids, and in the first place I took by definition that the Lie Groupoid inversion be smooth, but it came to my mind that it is a thing to demonstrate.

I tried to understand the demonstration in the *Mackenzie K.C.H General Theory of Lie Groupoids* but I failed to.

More precisely, this is the part that I don't understand:

Let $G$ the set of arrows, $G_0$ the set of objects of our groupoid and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the source and target map respectively.
Let $\theta : G \star G \longrightarrow G \times_\beta G$ a map defined by $(h,g) \longmapsto (h,hg)$ where $G \star G$ is the set of composable arrows and $G \times_\beta G$ the set of arrows that have the same target (and the product $hg$ is defined by the groupoid law.

$\theta$ is obviously bijective. I have a problem to show that it is an immersion:
Let $(h,g) \in G \star G$ and $(Y,X) \in T_{(h,g)} G \star G$ and suppose that $T_{(h,g)}\theta (Y,X) = (0,0)$.

In this part the book states that $\pi_2 \circ \theta = \pi_2$ and that implies that $Y=0$. But $\pi_2$ is not defined, I think that it is the second projection. However, later in the proof they said that $\pi_2 : G \star G \longrightarrow G$, but how can we then compose $\pi_2 \circ \theta$, that does not make any sens for me.

In addition, if we admit that $\pi_2$ is really the second projection defined in $G \times G$, $\pi_2 \circ \theta$ is equal to the law of the groupoid.

I'd really appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're limiting your answer pool to those who have that book at hand.  Could you share the proof that your struggling with, including the parts you understand and the parts you do not?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang I edited my question, I hope it is more clear now.